# Is is possible to call the child classes and the parent class from another python script dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

```
class Animal(self):
    def putData(self, dict)
        # do something

    @ abc.abstractmethod
    def getSum(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass


class Dog(Animal):
    def display(self):
        # do something

    def getSum(self,count):
        # do something

class Cat(Animal):
    def calculate(self):
        # do something

    def getSum(self,*dict):
        # do something
```

All these class files are in folder /username/pacagename/ and the python script from which i have to call these 4 classes is in /username/packagename/bin

Comment: So what was the question again?

Comment: from the python script which is in some bin directory, i have to call these sub classes dynamically. In such a way that the name of the child classes should not be hardcoded. How can it be done ??

Comment: Python code never cares what objects you throw around.

Comment: Yea, so is it possible that all the class files in that directory are executed. and how ?

Comment: What do you mean "executed"?  How will you use the classes without knowing their names?

Comment: that is what i meant by dynamically fetching their names and calling them

Comment: What do you mean "calling them"?  If you call a class you get an instance.  What will you *do* with it?

Comment: i just dont wanna hardcode it...so that if i add more classes in future...they will get executed automatically